# FFmpeg strftime microseconds

Tags: datetime, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i mymp.mp3 -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 5 13_REG1_CHANNEL3_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%s.mp3
```

Is it possible to add at filename microseconds ?

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` uses `strfmttime()` to create these filenames. You can use `%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f`to get as much precision as your system allows. Note the `%f` at the end.

## Update

Your example would be:

`ffmpeg -i mymp.mp3 -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 5 13_REG1_CHANNEL3_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%f.mp3`

Comment: if you mean segment -strftime 1 key, it doesn't work
it prints filename like "2020-03-15_18/44/59.f.mp3"

Comment: i did like you wrote
but is doesn't work
it looks like "13_REG1_CHANNEL3__2020-04-11_11-21-28-f.mp3